# Setting up an OpenVPN connection between my home network and a serve ro the internet

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

I want ot tunnel all local network traffic oven an OpneVPN connection. I have an ubuntu server configured on the internet (and it works from my laptop) and am now trying to configure the Raspberry to take all traffic on eth0 and tunnel it through eth1.

However, I cannot get it to work. I expected that there would now be a 'tun0' or so in ifconfig, but there is not:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:63:05:18  
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1974 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:130750 (127.6 KiB)  TX bytes:9302 (9.0 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0e:c6:fa:85:06  
          inet addr:192.168.0.252  Bcast:192.168.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:46828 errors:0 dropped:1006 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4085487 (3.8 MiB)  TX bytes:761137 (743.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:150 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:150 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:10495 (10.2 KiB)  TX bytes:10495 (10.2 KiB)
```

I did add the following rules to iptables (and adoption of a tutorial)

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE -m comment --comment "Use VPN IP for eth0"
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE -m comment --comment "Use VPN IP for tun0"
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s192.168.0.0/24 -i eth1 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j REJECT -m comment --comment "Block traffic from clients to eth0"
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s192.168.0.0/24 -i eth1 -o tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow only traffic from clients to tun0"
```

But with tun0 not existing, I guess nothing will redirect.
And also, while the internet connection works on the RPi, it does not go through the tunnel, but directly to the internet.

Finally, this is my config file for openVPN (with the certs removed at the end):

```
##############################################
# Sample client-side OpenVPN 2.0 config file #
# for connecting to multi-client server.     #
#                                            #
# This configuration can be used by multiple #
# clients, however each client should have   #
# its own cert and key files.                #
#                                            #
# On Windows, you might want to rename this  #
# file so it has a .ovpn extension           #
##############################################

# Specify that we are a client and that we
# will be pulling certain config file directives
# from the server.
client

# Use the same setting as you are using on
# the server.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

#ifconfig 10.8.0.2 10.8.0.1

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel
# if you have more than one.  On XP SP2,
# you may need to disable the firewall
# for the TAP adapter.
;dev-node MyTap

# Are we connecting to a TCP or
# UDP server?  Use the same setting as
# on the server.
;proto tcp
proto udp

# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194
;remote my-server-2 1194

# Choose a random host from the remote
# list for load-balancing.  Otherwise
# try hosts in the order specified.
;remote-random

# Keep trying indefinitely to resolve the
# host name of the OpenVPN server.  Very useful
# on machines which are not permanently connected
# to the internet such as laptops.
resolv-retry infinite

# Most clients don't need to bind to
# a specific local port number.
nobind

# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
user nobody
group nogroup

# Try to preserve some state across restarts.
persist-key
persist-tun

# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]

# Wireless networks often produce a lot
# of duplicate packets.  Set this flag
# to silence duplicate packet warnings.
;mute-replay-warnings

# SSL/TLS parms.
# See the server config file for more
# description.  It's best to use
# a separate .crt/.key file pair
# for each client.  A single ca
# file can be used for all clients.
#ca ca.crt
#cert client.crt
#key client.key

# Verify server certificate by checking
# that the certicate has the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  This is an
# important precaution to protect against
# a potential attack discussed here:
#  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm
#
# To use this feature, you will need to generate
# your server certificates with the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  The build-key-server
# script in the easy-rsa folder will do this.
ns-cert-type server

# If a tls-auth key is used on the server
# then every client must also have the key.
;tls-auth ta.key 1

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# If the cipher option is used on the server
# then you must also specify it here.
;cipher x

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# Don't enable this unless it is also
# enabled in the server config file.
comp-lzo

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages
;mute 20
```

These are the log items in syslog:

```
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3279]: OpenVPN 2.2.1 arm-linux-gnueabihf [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Dec  1 2014
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3279]: NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3279]: LZO compression initialized
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3279]: Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3279]: Socket Buffers: R=[163840->131072] S=[163840->131072]
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3279]: Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3279]: Local Options hash (VER=V4): '41690919'
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3279]: Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '530fdded'
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]185.27.174.62:1194
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]185.27.174.62:1194, sid=9bf9a964 2f78ece0
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=IE/ST=KE/L=xxx/O=xxx/OU=IT/CN=VPN_tunnel_cert/name=server/emailAddress=xxx
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Apr 12 16:06:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=IE/ST=KE/L=xxx/O=xxx/OU=IT/CN=server/name=server/emailAddress=xxx
Apr 12 16:07:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Apr 12 16:07:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Apr 12 16:07:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Apr 12 16:07:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Apr 12 16:07:26 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: Re-using SSL/TLS context
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: LZO compression initialized
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: Socket Buffers: R=[163840->131072] S=[163840->131072]
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: Local Options hash (VER=V4): '41690919'
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '530fdded'
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1194
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]185.27.174.62:1194, sid=d2b65489 e5492d4d
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=IE/ST=KE/L=xxx/O=xxx/OU=IT/CN=VPN_tunnel_cert/name=server/emailAddress=xxx
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Apr 12 16:07:28 raspberrypi ovpn-server[3280]: VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=IE/ST=KE/L=xxx/O=xxx/OU=IT/CN=server/name=server/emailAddress=xxx
```

Comment: The syslog messages don’t indicate a connection was established. [This is a complete initialization log](http://pastebin.com/g6diauCF) with `verb 3`.

Comment: Ok, I re-ran, and now get the response as I updated in the post. There seems to be a problem with the TLS handshake.

Comment: Ok, there was a problem with the certificate, I used another one (of my laptop) and it worked.